# "nt authority\system" can't use exec() on apache

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I am running a php script on apache but I have been unable to get exec() to work. When I do echo exec('whoami') it says "nt authority\system" so I am assumming "nt authority\system" does not have permission to execute or there is some other problem.

How can I get "nt authority\system" to be able to use exec()

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `exec()` and the other similar functions are notoriously bad for doing anything but the most basic CLI commans

Comment: @Machavity yes I am trying to exec() a command, when I do exec('the command') on the command line after starting php it works, it just doesnt work in the script on apache

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt, use whoami to see the account it uses. Then in Services, find your Apace instance, properties, and Log On. Select This Account and add the account command prompt is using.